# Windows patching is automatic or manual

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

Might be you guys never encountered anything like this. Here are the situations.
We have around **2500+ servers** (**win 2003/2008/2012**). Monthly Windows patching done by two way.

1. Assigned the patch to servers by **SCCM/WSUS/BSA**, then login manually on the server and download and install the patches. After installation reboot the server. This is a manual patching in our terms.
2. Assigned, download and install the patch to servers by **SCCM/WSUS/BSA** and then reboot the server manually. We called this as Automatic patching.

Now i have to prepare list of servers by patching type (**Manual & Automatic**).

**Is there any registry key or anything where i can check windows patching is automatic or manual?**

Once i get that info then i will create a script and run on all the server.

Can anybody advise me on this?

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @user2301394 How are you deploying these updates via SCCM?  Surely you'd be deploying this to a collection populated with objects?

Comment: @JoeS Yes, through collection but problem is servers are not from single customer there are multiple customer and deployment of updates are different. Some use SCCM/WSUS/BSA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this registry key,

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU

```
AUOptions
Reg_DWORD
Range = 2|3|4|5
2 = Notify before download.
3 = Automatically download and notify of installation. 
4 = Automatically download and schedule installation. Only valid if values exist for ScheduledInstallDay and ScheduledInstallTime.
5 = Automatic Updates is required and users can configure it.
```

List of all registry keys relating to Windows Update:

> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score -1):

- Go to `GPEDIT.msc`
- Expand `Windows`
- Expand `Windows Components`
- Expand `Windows Update`
- Check `Auto Configure` option on the right side